# How to remove a team from Slack

Tags: applications

Is it possible to remove a team from the Slack app for Android, without uninstalling and reinstalling the app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

Connect to the team you wish to remove and tap the vertical elipsis menu. Go to "Settings".  Scroll down until you see "Sign out of " in red. Tap it and confirm.